# Hiding specific rows columns according to specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hide, conditional-formatting

I have the following table:

```
First Name  Second Name Phone TF
A                B       1     True
A                B       2     False
C                D       3     True
C                D       4     False
```

I would like to hide column First Name and Second Name only if the value of the TF in the relevant row is False.

The result table would be as followed:

```
First Name  Second Name Phone TF
A                B       1     True
                         2     False
C                D       3     True
                         4     False
```

If there is a wide to hide all TF column it would be good.

Comment: Uhh tried filter yet?

Comment: I need it to be done automatically not manually. Can filter be better in this case than conditional formatting?

Comment: Conditional formatting doesn't hide. And a macro can filter automatically if that's what you want. Edit: well, you will have to press a button.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without macro? I think there is a trick in conditional formatting to paint the relevant cells in white.

Comment: OH. You don't want it hidden per say. Yea, you can paint it white via conditional formatting.

Comment: Create a CF rule based upon the formula `=not($D2)`. Use a custom number format of `;;;`.

Comment: @ Jeeped  and findwindow Can you explain how to do it practically?

Comment: @ pnuts FALSE is a calculation of a formula that its results is TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @Jeeped that's cool ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `First Name` is in A1, please select ColumnsA:B and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$D1=FALSE
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Font  Color white, OK, OK.